# Twitter, how to get user's oauth secret by twitter username without twitter connection

Tags: php, twitter

I found the access key by using the appid and customer key in the facebook.

In the same may i get the access token and the access secret key for the particular user by using their username?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me i needed suggestion

Comment: Do you mean it for twitter or fb ? I asked this because you used twitter tag here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get a **user access secret** using only the username.

The point of using tokens is to enable applications to act in regard of the user without using username/passwords combinations. Therefore it is important to ask the user to allow the application to perform authenticated calls, and through this flow get a unique set of access/secret tokens that you could use to perform API calls.

You can see some of the flows to get user access tokens [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens).

You can get an application key and secret by creating an application in https://dev.twitter.com. Under the application screen you will be able to generate access and secret for **your own user** but not for other users.